# Add all IPV6 pool /64 addresses to eth0 on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, reverse-proxy, ipv6

I would like to bind an application to different IPV6 addresses on my network interface. Currently the /64 pool is correctly routed to my server and I can ping all addresses but Applications still can not bind to them even they are added to the config.

For ex I binded the pool using:

```
ip route add local 2a01:xx:xx:xx::/64 dev lo
```

But when I run

```
ip -6 address list
```

I can not see any of the routed addresses so I add them one by one like

```
ip -6 addr add 2a01:xx:xx:xx::1/64 dev eth0
```

I guess that my application can not bind to it. Any clue how can I get around then otherwise will have to create a bash script with a huge loop?

PS. The application is a Golang app I am writing but I also tested with Tinyproxy with BindSame option which still does not work!

Comment: An interface can have multiple IPv6 addresses, but you will need to configure each individually. Remember that, unlike IPv4, all the addresses in an IPv6 network are valid host addresses, including the network address. If you configure the `2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64` address on the interface, you are configuring that single address on the interface. You will not live nearly long enough to assign all the possible host addresses in a `/64` network to an interface, and the OS will not let you do that, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! so any workaround would allow me to use those few million addresses?

Comment: It's not a few million addresses, but actually millions of millions of millions of addresses (`18,446,744,073,709,551,616` possible addresses in a standard IPv6 `/64` network). Your OS will let you assign a few dozen, at the most, addresses to an interface.

Comment: At one million addresses assigned per second, it will take you well over half a million years to assign all the addresses, but your OS will not even do that.

Comment: I understand..What about a VPN?

Comment: I don't follow. A VPN is a tunnel, basically a link that has endpoints, each of which is assigned one or more addresses, but those interfaces are subject to the limitations of the OS on the device where the endpoint interface is. I think you are looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: You are right. The application will still need a network interface to bind to. I just do not understand how come the whole pool is routed to my interface yet I can not feely bind my application to any IP in that pool! any ideas?

Comment: You are confusing a few things. You are given a network, much like what you may be give for IPv4. You could assign one of the addresses to the interface, and the rest could be used by other things from a virtual bridge. You can assign addresses from that network in many ways. For example, if you have a bunch of VMs, you can assign each its own address. IPv6 also has delegation, where a router is delegated a smaller prefix, and it can assign different networks from the longer prefixes that make up the smaller prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the request IP to the current interface within the application logic. Of course this depends on the security measures on the app.

As far as all IPs were correctly routed to the server

```
/sbin/ip route add local 2a01:xx:xx:xx::/64 dev lo
```

For ex in my case using Golang

```
exec.Command("/sbin/ip", "addr", "add", "2a01:xx:xx:xx::1/64", "dev", "eth0").Output()
```